# How to use Spring actuator metrics to non Spring apps

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is it possible (in any way) to use Spring actuator metrics to Non-Spring apps (for eg Web services in Jersey or RestEasy)?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: There is an open [issue #1169](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/1169) to add support for RestEasy to Micrometer.